# Mongodb Search nested array elements

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a below data. Would like to search aclpermissions where any of the elements (CRT, READ, DLT, UPD) will match to an array of inputs.

Below query

```
db.AMSAppACL.find({"aclpermissions.READ" : {'$in': ['58dc0bea0cd182789fc62fab']}}).pretty();
```

only searches READ element. Is there any way to search all the elements instead of using or queries and aggregate

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5900d6abb9eb284a78f5a350"),
        "_class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.AMSAppACL",
        "attrUniqueCode" : "USER",
        "attributeVersion" : 1,
        "aclpermissions" : {
                "CRT" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"
                ],
                "READ" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa",
                        "58dc0bea0cd182789fc62fab"
                ],
                "UPD" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"
                ],
                "DLT" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"
                ]
        },
        "orgHierachyIdentifier" : "14",
        "orgid" : 14,
        "createDate" : ISODate("2017-04-26T17:19:39.026Z"),
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-04-26T17:19:39.026Z"),
        "createdBy" : "appadmin",
        "lastModifiedBy" : "appadmin"
}
```

Comment: You should create key value pairs if you can do schema changes. Key being name and value being array of ids.

Comment: It is still key value pair. <stirng key> : [value: array of strings]. Do you want me to do something else i.e. taking it out of aclpermissions? if yes then also how will I achieve my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try updating  `aclpermissions` part of schema from dynamic keys to labeled keys.

```
"aclpermissions":
     [
       {k:"CRT", v: ["58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"]},
       {k:"READ", v: [ "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa", "58dc0bea0cd182789fc62fab"]}....
     ]
```

Now you can update the query from post to something like

```
db.AMSAppACL.find({"aclpermissions.v" : {'$in': ['58dc0bea0cd182789fc62fab']}}).pretty();
```