# Mongodb select particular element form an nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have below MongoDB object structure. I would like to select aclpermissions based on values (using Spring MogoTemplate). e.g. if I pass "58dc0bea0cd182789fc62fab" it should return only aclpermissions.READ but if I pass "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa" it should return all the aclpermissions.

How to achieve that. if I have to modify data structure please suggests what to do and how to achieve that.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5900d6abb9eb284a78f5a350"),
        "_class" : "com.debopam.amsapp.model.AMSAppACL",
        "attrUniqueCode" : "USER",
        "attributeVersion" : 1,
        "aclpermissions" : {
                "CRT" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"
                ],
                "READ" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa",
                        "58dc0bea0cd182789fc62fab"
                ],
                "UPD" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"
                ],
                "DLT" : [
                        "58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"
                ]
        },
        "orgHierachyIdentifier" : "14",
        "orgid" : 14,
        "createDate" : ISODate("2017-04-26T17:19:39.026Z"),
        "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2017-04-26T17:19:39.026Z"),
        "createdBy" : "appadmin",
        "lastModifiedBy" : "appadmin"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same updated structure from [Mongodb Search nested array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665112/mongodb-search-nested-array-elements)

You can use the below aggregation query with `$filter` array operator with `$setIsSubset` query operator, which compares and selects the nested document where input value is a subset of `aclpermission.v`.

```
 import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.Filter.filter;
 import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;
 import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

  Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
          match(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId("5900d6abb9eb284a78f5a350"))),
          project()
               .and(filter("aclpermissions")
                                .as("aclpermission")
                                .by(aggregationOperationContext -> new BasicDBObject("$setIsSubset", asList(asList("58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"), "$$aclpermission.v"))))
         .as("aclpermissions")
  );

 List<BasicDBObject> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName,  BasicDBObject.class).getMappedResults();
```

Mongo Shell query:

```
aggregate([ { "$match" : { "_id" : ObjectId("5900d6abb9eb284a78f5a350")}} , { "$project" : { "aclpermissions" : { "$filter" : { "input" : "$aclpermissions" , "as" : "aclpermission" , "cond" : { "$setIsSubset" : [ ["58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"], "$$aclpermission.v"]}}}}}])
```

Update:

The below query will `$match` documents with  `attrUniqueCode` value equal to `USER` followed by `$sort` and `$group` the pick the latest document. `$$ROOT` is expression variable to access the whole document with `$first` to get the latest one.

```
 Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
         match(Criteria.where("attrUniqueCode").is("USER")),
         sort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "attributeVersion")),
         group().first("$$ROOT").as("latest"),
         project("latest._id", "latest.attrUniqueCode", "latest.attributeVersion")
                        .and(filter("latest.aclpermissions")
                                .as("aclpermission")
                                .by(aggregationOperationContext -> new BasicDBObject("$setIsSubset", asList(asList("58dc0bd70cd182789fc62faa"), "$$aclpermission.v"))))
         .as("aclpermissions")
  );
```

Reference

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Comment: Thanks. Will test this and let you know.

Comment: This works. but as I asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667611/mongotemplate-aggregation-and-select-one-row could you please let know how to integrate that. Considering for a "attrUniqueCode" there can be multiple "attributeVersion". How to select latest one i.e. record with the highest version.

Comment: You are welcome. Updated to include the filter from the other post. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks it worked. But could you please explain to me what is happening here. $$ROOT, Project and filter etc.

Comment: You are welcome. Add some more description and links